# dynamic add-view with ID

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

i am creating an application, which i use to create a list of things that i have in `SQLite` database

i created a Fragment with a button that add a `xml` file to my `LinearLayout` , it works good , but i want to grab EditText and Spinner data and put them in a `JSONobject` but i don't know how , i don't have IDs of dynamically created views

[image]

## My Fragment XML

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_add"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## My field (addView) XML

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:onClick="onIncrease"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:onClick="onDecrease"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="@string/number"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Fragment.java File

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newfactor,container,false);

        fab = v.findViewById(R.id.addItem);
        ln = v.findViewById(R.id.itemsContainer);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);

                final EditText editText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.number);
                Button add = rowView.findViewById(R.id.add);
                Button remove = rowView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                Button clear = rowView.findViewById(R.id.clear);
                Spinner spinner = rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

                list = new ArrayList<>();

                dbConnector = new DbConnector(getContext(),null,null,1);

                Cursor c = dbConnector.get().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product",null);

                while (c.moveToNext()){
                    int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    String desc = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description"));
                    String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("price"));

                    list.add(new SpinnerObject(id,name,price));

                }

                spinnerAdapter = new ir.animelist.localshop.Adaptors.SpinnerAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


                add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                        int num_num = num + 1;
                        editText.setText(num_num + "");
                    }
                });

                remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                        if(num > 0){
                            int num_num = num - 1;
                            editText.setText(num_num + "");
                        }

                    }
                });

                clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ln.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                    }
                });

                ln.addView(rowView, ln.getChildCount() - 1);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: For lists use RecyclerView not LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `recyclerview` to display your list items. Using `recyclerview` you can get view like -

```
View view = recyclerview.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos).itemView;
Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
```

This will return you a `spinner` of whichever position you have passed and afterwards get data from it. 
Similarly, you can get view of `edittext` by using -

```
EditText edtTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.myEdtTxt);
```

To see how to get data from database and display that in `recyclerview`, check the example here - https://github.com/incipientinfo/db-queries